# MySQL string searching technique?

Tags: java, mysql, database, search

In my android app, I have a search field where the user can type something. They can type anything they want like names, addresses, phone numbers, emails, etc... in my database.

I want it to be like an all in one search bar in google search, so they can type combinations of things like a name with an address for example.

The problem is how would I do a search where the search text can contain multiple phrases?

For example if the user searched "Jack Daniel jdaniel@hotmail.com", then I would want mysql select statement to end up being like:

```
select id from members
where firstname=`Jack` or firstname=`Daniel` or firstname=`jdaniel@hotmail.com`
   or lastname=`Jack` or lastname=`Daniel` or lastname=`jdaniel@hotmail.com`
   or email=`Jack` or email=`Daniel` or email=`jdaniel@hotmail.com`
```

Basically each phrase of the search text needs to be compared with all the columns.

Does MySQL have a built in mechanism to do this easily, or do I have to parse the string in java and manually build the sql statement?

Thanks

Comment: You probably will need to parse before going to SQL, like for e-mail, you need parse it locally if it can be typed or not in any place of the search phrase. You can not distinguish what is a name, or an address, other than the formating the user can do, so depending on that, you can need to search in other fields.

Answer (score 1):

Users like a "quick search", and for usability I think this works best matching anywhere in the string -- therefore a LIKE '%Jack%' condition.

I don't bother to separate fields & clauses out for the "quick search". (For a full-weight search form I have separate inputs for each field the user can search on.) But quick search is a simple UI.

I do it case-insensitive. If it's not your DB's default, you can use a `lower()` function on the string before matching.

For input 'Jacks':

```
select * from members 
where fullname like '%Jacks%' or email like '%Jacks%'
```

Or, like I do in FireBird to force case-insensitivity:

```
select * from members 
where lower(fullname) like '%jacks%' or lower(email) like '%jacks%'
```

This would match all of:

```
fullname='Mike Jackson'
fullname='Jackson Five'
fullname='Lumberjacks R Us'
email='phil@jackstrucking.com'
```

You can keep the first and lastname fields separate, if you want..  my designs prefer to keep them together, since I mainly just use the fullname for display purposes & don't care as to distinctions.

Comment: so when you say `LIKE`, that means `is a substring of`?

Comment: `%` is the multi-character wildcard in LIKE, equivalent to * in filenames (`_` is equivalent to ?). `LIKE 'a%'` matches strings starting with 'a', `LIKE '%a'` matches strings ending with 'a', and `LIKE '%a%'` matches 'a' anywhere in the string.

Comment: And just wondering about case sensitivity -- since SQLite comes with the Android platform, why are you asking about MySQL?

Comment: Im using a free web server that uses php and mysql. Also is this condition true: `jack LIKE %jack daniels%`? (`jack daniels` would be the search text, and `jack` would be the columns value)

Comment: No, "%jack daniels%" is too specific & too long to match just "jack". If your users want Jack Daniels, they'll probably search for "daniels" or "jack" first anyway --  they typically search for a short distinctive word or phrase first. If they're specifically looking for "daniels", they don't want to see just Jack.

Answer (score 0):

I think the wild card will help you a little bit.
Check it out here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

My suggestion is try adding a column named FULLNAME for example, then can use something like this:

```
select id from members where
fullname='%Jack%' or fullname="%Daniel%" or email="%jack%" or email="%daniel%"
```